# Error: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the Initialized state

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy Trabajando con conexiones bidireccionales de sql server local hacia firestore database ya logre mandar datos de sql server hacia la nube, el inconveniente viene ya que al querer tener la conexión bidireccional, tiene el mensaje de:

```
Error al actualizar el registro: RequestError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the Initialized state

code: 'EINVALIDSTATE',
  number: undefined,
  state: undefined,
  class: undefined,
  serverName: undefined,
  procName: undefined,
  lineNumber: undefined
```

El código que hasta ahorita tengo es el siguiente:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { Connection, Request } = require('tedious');

// Configuración de Firebase
var serviceAccount = require("./testconectsql.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

const collectionRef = admin.firestore().collection('UsersTest');

// Configuración de la base de datos SQL Server
const config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: '12345',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'testToFirebase',
    port: 1433,
    options: {
        trustServerCertificate: true
    } 
};

// Conexión a la base de datos SQL Server
const connection = new Connection(config);
connection.on('connect', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error de conexión:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Conexión exitosa.');
    // Consulta los datos y actualiza la colección de Firebase
    const request = new Request('SELECT * FROM UsersTest', (err, rowCount, rows) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error en la consulta:', err);
      } else {
        console.log('Número de filas obtenidas:', rowCount);
        rows.forEach((row) => {
          const newRow = {
            Name: row.Name.value,
            PhoneNumber: row.PhoneNumber.value,
            EmployeeNumber: row.EmployeeNumber.value,
            RolUser: row.RolUser.value
          };
          const docId = row.Id.value.toString(); // convertir el Id numérico a string
          collectionRef.doc(docId).set(newRow)
            .then(() => console.log('Documento actualizado exitosamente'))
            .catch((err) => console.error('Error al actualizar el documento:', err));
        });
      }
      connection.close();
    });
    connection.execSql(request);
  }
});

// Escuchar cambios en la colección de Firebase y actualizar SQL Server
collectionRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
    if (change.type === 'added' || change.type === 'modified') {
      const newData = change.doc.data();
      const docId = change.doc.id;
      const request = new Request(`UPDATE UsersTest SET Name='${newData.Name}', PhoneNumber='${newData.PhoneNumber}', EmployeeNumber='${newData.EmployeeNumber}', RolUser='${newData.RolUser}' WHERE Id=${docId}`, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error al actualizar el registro:', err);
        } else {
          console.log('Registro actualizado exitosamente');
        }
      });
      connection.execSql(request);
    } else if (change.type === 'removed') {
      const docId = change.doc.id;
      const request = new Request(`DELETE FROM UsersTest WHERE Id=${docId}`, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error al eliminar el registro:', err);
        } else {
          console.log('Registro eliminado exitosamente');
        }
      });
      connection.execSql(request);
    }
  });
});
```